# Restrict parent from getting focus clicking on one of its children

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout`, that has two others layouts inside of it. What I want to do is to let to the parent layout to get focus when I click on the area of the first children layout (so `onClick()` method will be called for the parent), and do nothing when I click on the area of the second children.

`descendantsFocusability` doesn't work in my case, since it defines focusability for all the children and it's the same for all of them (which is clearly not my case).

Answer (score 1):

First set this attribute to the layouts in the xml-files:

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Then you can, by applying [`requestFocus()`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html), shift the focuses around your
layouts.